# Laravel 4 RESTful routing

Tags: rest, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying make restful routing and in guide is - 
Defining A RESTful Controller:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

so i can now call: (GET) users/new, users/add BUT how i can make URL like this: /registration, /login ? Is this correct and restful?

```
Route::get('registration', 'UserController@registration');
Route::get('login', 'UserController@login');
```

Answer (score 0):

If "registration" and "login" are actions inside your UserController, then yes, this is the way.

Comment: Thaks! One last question: Is necessarily define that controller with Route::controller()? Or suffices Route::get, Route::post... to define URLs?

Comment: The pattern goes like this: Route::method('URI', 'controller@action'. Method could be post or get, depending on your needs or "any" if registering a route that responds to any HTTP verb.

Comment: Yes i understand pattern. So routing RESTful controller (UserController) with different URLs (/login;/user;/registration) is same as normal controllers? (of course in UserController have actions like getRegistration, postRegistrate, getLogin....)